# is there any way to discard image files in oracle database?

Tags: oracle

```html
<?php
$conn = oci_connect('ABCC', 'abcAA', 'orrfgfd2/UID1');
if (!$conn) {
   $m = oci_error();
   echo $m['message'], "\n";
   exit;
}
else {
   
 $d = new DateTime();
 $yesterday = $d->sub(new DateInterval('P1D'))->format('Y.m.d');
 $filename = "access.$yesterday.txt";

 if(file_exists($filename)){
  $myfile = fopen($filename, "r");
  while(!feof($myfile)) {
   $content= fgets($myfile);
    
   $carray=explode(',',$content);
   list($IP_ADDRESS, $USER_IDENTIFIER, $USERID , $REQUEST_TIME , $CLIENT_REQUEST ,$RESPONSE_CODE ,$SIZEOFOBJECT, $COOKIES)=$carray;
    
   $stdii = 'INSERT INTO LOGS(IP_ADDRESS, USER_IDENTIFIER, USERID , REQUEST_TIME , CLIENT_REQUEST ,RESPONSE_CODE ,SIZEOFOBJECT, COOKIES)'.
   'values(:IP_ADDRESS, :USER_IDENTIFIER, :USERID , :REQUEST_TIME , :CLIENT_REQUEST ,:RESPONSE_CODE ,:SIZEOFOBJECT, :COOKIES)';
   $compiled1 = oci_parse($conn, $stdii);
   oci_bind_by_name($compiled1, ':IP_ADDRESS', $IP_ADDRESS);
   oci_bind_by_name($compiled1, ':USER_IDENTIFIER', $USER_IDENTIFIER);
   oci_bind_by_name($compiled1,':USERID', $USERID);
   oci_bind_by_name($compiled1, ':REQUEST_TIME', $REQUEST_TIME);
   oci_bind_by_name($compiled1, ':CLIENT_REQUEST', $CLIENT_REQUEST);
   oci_bind_by_name($compiled1, ':RESPONSE_CODE', $RESPONSE_CODE);
   oci_bind_by_name($compiled1, ':SIZEOFOBJECT', $SIZEOFOBJECT);
   oci_bind_by_name($compiled1, ':COOKIES', $COOKIES);
   oci_execute($compiled1, OCI_COMMIT_ON_SUCCESS);
   
   
   
   }
   $message="File Uploaded";
   echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert(\"$message\");</script>";
  
   fclose($myfile);
 }
 
 else{
  $message2="File Doesn't exists";
  echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert(\"$message2\");</script>";
  
 }

}
oci_close($conn);

?>
```

I have designed a script which will upload log file data to oracle database. However i want to filter images in my data upload. Here in this case,i don't want my code to upload CLIENT_REQUEST("GET /icons/back.gif HTTP/1.1") having .gif extensions in my request. Can someone please help me with the query.

My Log File

```
127.0.0.1,-,-,[06/Aug/2018:09:22:02 +0200],"GET /icons/back.gif HTTP/1.1",304,-,"-"
127.0.0.1,-,-,[06/Aug/2018:09:22:02 +0200],"GET /icons/blank.gif HTTP/1.1",304,-,"-"
127.0.0.1,-,-,[06/Aug/2018:09:22:02 +0200],"GET /icons/unknown.gif HTTP/1.1",304,-,"-"
127.0.0.1,-,-,[06/Aug/2018:09:22:02 +0200],"GET /icons/image2.gif HTTP/1.1",304,-,"-"
127.0.0.1,-,-,[06/Aug/2018:09:22:02 +0200],"GET /icons/text.gif HTTP/1.1",304,-,"-"
```

Comment: What is you script doing, and how does it load the data? You might just want to filter the rows from the source data e.g. with `grep`, but it depends what you are doing already. An external table could use a preprocessor to do the same thing. Or you can filter it after loading. Etc.

Comment: I have added my code. I am taking my log file(txt file) data and inserting into oracle database. However i want to discard image data to upload to my table.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the log file as an external table, then you can *load* it via (PL/)SQL and actually write a `WHERE` clause which will reject such rows. For example:

```
insert into your_table (col1, col2, ...)
select ... 
from log_file_as_external_table
where instr(log_file_line, '.gif HTTP/1.1') = 0
```